# Electron RPi: Requested device not found (camera)

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, electron, gstreamer, chromium

I'm building an Electron streaming app that I deploy on Raspberry Pi 3 with attached camera (OV5647 5Mpx) that supposedly supports YUV/RAW WGB formats. When I try to access it via:

```js
const constraints = {"video": true}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
```

I get an error: `DOMException: Requested device not found` and basically no further details.

I also have a different app based on gstreamer and it is able to stream image from this camera with following input settings (it works on the same device):

```
gst_parse_launch ("webrtcbin bundle-policy=max-bundle name=sendrecv "
        TURN_SERVER
        "v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! v4l2h264enc ! video/x-h264,level=(string)3.1,stream-format=(string)byte-stream ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! "  
        "" RTP_CAPS_H264 "96 ! sendrecv. "
        "alsasrc device=hw:0 ! audioamplify amplification=15 ! audio/x-raw,channels=(int)2,format=(string)S32LE,rate=(int)44100,layout=(string)interleaved ! deinterleave name=d d.src_0 ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! webrtcdsp echo-suppression-level=2 noise-suppression-level=3 voice-detection=true ! queue ! audioconvert ! opusenc ! rtpopuspay ! "
        "queue ! " RTP_CAPS_OPUS "97 ! sendrecv. ", &error);
```

My question is, what would be the further steps to analyse why Chromium can't recognize my camera? Is it a matter of drivers or rather app configuration?
Also, would it be possible to acquire the video stream directly from gstreamer somehow? And pass it further to WebRTC PeerConnection within Electron app, not using the `UserMedia` at all?

**EDIT:**

I've tried opening the same application via a browser on a desktop version of Raspbian (same code hosted as a webpage on an external server). It failed with the same error on Chrome, but worked on Firefox. So seems like Chrome backend cannot communicate with the camera. *How is it different from the Firefox backend and how to include the missing bits manually?*

**FYI:**

I've filed a bug report in Chromium as it appears to be a problem since 89.0.4389.128 version https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1259138